# How does one call civicrm_api3_system_check API

Tags: wordpress, api, 4.7

What are the valid parameters to pass to civicrm_api3_system_check($params)?

Passing $params = false or $params = array() causes an infinite loop despite my try catch.

**../civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/System.php** gives no hints

**../civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/examples/System/Flush.php** only shows how to use System flush

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example of calling `System.check` with an empty `$params` array should work. For example, this is what I get if I call the API from [the command line](https://github.com/civicrm/cv):

```
$ cv php:eval 'return civicrm_api3("System","check", array());'
{
    "is_error": 0,
    "version": 3,
    "count": 6,
    "values": {
        "1": {
            "name": "checkExtensionUpgrades",
            "message": "Extension upgrades are pending.  Please visit <a href=\"/civicrm/admin/extensions/upgrade?reset=1\">the upgrade page</a> to run them.",
            "title": "Run Extension Upgrades",
            "severity": "error",
            "severity_id": 4,
            "is_visible": 1,
            "icon": "fa-plug",
            "id": 1
        },
        ...
```

(For other media, you can use the API Explorer to get code snippets.)

There are a lot of checks, and it's possible that they're slow on some systems. Alternatively, maybe one of the checks has a bug, relies on an incorrect assumption about the environment or data, or has an interaction with third-party code?

Comment: So do not call it directly, but via civicrm_api3("System","check", array()). Would be nice if the examples in ../civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/examples/System/. showed the parameters to run the other System.php methods. Thank you Tim

Comment: Good point, one does have to use `civicrm_api3()`. I take that for granted. This may be interesting: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/api/usage/

Comment: Another API action called HELP is needed. Then civicrm_api3("System", "HELP", array()) could display all possible actions and parameters. By the way CHECK, is not in that API action list nor anywhere else. Self documenting code, what a concept.